# Using Form type of form type to handle ImageUploading on symfony form

Tags: php, forms, symfony, types

How to create a custom form type from two form type. I want to create ImageFileType that has two form type inside it one for handling image file and one hidden form type for check that does user change the image on editing action.

This hidden field is because of when user goes for editing entity and just edit other form field and do not edit imageFiletype this form sent empty file to server and I need hidden form field to know that is the user change entity image or not.

I add two form type to this new form type (PromotImageformtype) and want to get the value of second field and send it back to my main form type.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('ImageChangeFlag', 'hidden', array('data' => false))
            ->add('image', 'imagefile', array('label' => 'لوگو راهکار',
                                                      'required' => false,
                                                      'image_path' => $options['image_path'])
                                                      'image_thumb_path' => $options['image_thumb_path']),
                                                      'entity' => $options['entity']),
                                                      'thumbs_info' => $options['thumbs_info'])
                                                    ));

        //add event listener to calls validator
        $ImageChangeFlag_listener = new ImageChangeFlagListener($options);
        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_BIND, array($ImageChangeFlag_listener, "PreBindValidatorImage"));

        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_BIND, array($ImageChangeFlag_listener, "PostBindValidatorImage"));
    }
```

how can I do this and at this situation how PRE_BIND and POST_BIND do their job I have form of two form type my parent form type has PRE_BIND and MY children form type also has PRE_BIND and POST_BIND listener.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this doc to learn how to save and update uploaded file

[How to handle File Uploads with Doctrine](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html)

and this for [How to Embed a Collection of Forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html)

Comment: I checked above link but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

Check for [Genemu bundle](https://github.com/genemu/GenemuFormBundle) which add differents form type such as file upload and image upload

[demo here](http://tympanus.net/crop1.1/)

I took inspiration to create my own